# Doctrine find() method returns stdClass instead of entity instance

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I did some searching around and didn't get an answer that would help me.

I'm using doctrine with symfony 2 and according to Doctrine's documentation (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-primary-key), the find() method should return either null or an instance of the entity.

The following code returns a stdClass instead when a valid client id is passed and an exception is thrown anyway. The entity manager is being injected to the service's constructor.

Using the commented check for an object works as it should and the exception's not thrown.

```
$client = $this->em->find('Entity\Clients\Client', $clientId);

\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($client);

//if (!is_object($client)) {
if (!$client instanceof Entity\Clients\Client) {
    throw new ClientDoesNotExistException($clientId);
}
```

Does nyone have an explanation for this? Am I missing something really basic?

Thanks.

Thank you Cerad. My doctrine bit in config.yml is the following

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: true
    filters:
        portal_filter:  path\to\BaseBundle\Filter\PortalFilter
        enabled:        true;'
```

Composer.json

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.13.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "1.5.3",
    "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
    "dunglas/angular-csrf-bundle": "1.0.*@dev",
    "oldsound/rabbitmq-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "oyejorge/less.php": "~1.5",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "dev-master",
    "peekmo/jsonpath": "dev-master",
    "uecode/api-key-bundle": "dev-master",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-zf2": "1.2.*"},
"require-dev": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
    "liip/functional-test-bundle":"dev-master"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.5-dev"
    }
}
}
```

Same issue, this time from the controller. FYI, previously I was injecting doctrine's entity manager in to the service like this:

```
DocumentManager:
    class: DocumentHandlerBundle\Services\DocumentManager
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

In the controller:

```
public function newDocumentAction() {          
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->find('Entity\Documents\Document', 1400);

    echo get_class($entity); // output: Entity\Documents\Document

    if ($entity instanceof Entity\Documents\Document) {
        echo "<p>YEYYY, we have an entity!!!</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>&/%#$&%#, not an entity!!!</p>";
    }
    return new Response('');
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you have another bundle with some specialized entity listeners.  Either that or you adjusted your doctrine configuration to something unusual.  Start by posting your applications composer.json file and the doctrine portion of app/config.yml.

Comment: Thanks Cerad. Added those to my question above.

Comment: So comment out the filters stuff in config.yml and I bet you will get your entity.  Then go see what the filter is supposed to be doing.  It's probably intercepting onLoad and converting your entity class to a std class.

Comment: @Cerad - Thanks for the tip. It didn't work though. I'm still getting a standard class as the output of find().

Comment: @Cerad - I'm having the same issue when I run the code straight from the controller as per the code above... so strange :S thanks for your help.

Comment: As you surmised, $em->find should return an entity.  But Doctrine 2 is flexible and you can insert filters and what not to change the normal behavior.  I'm pretty sure that is what is happening here.  For mysteries like these, I sometimes just start over with a new project, verify the find works (maybe make a simple command or test case) and then start adding in additional bundles.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Cerad. I'll try that. Will give you a shout as soon as I sort this out. Cheers.